# Facebook SDK: feeds don't work fine on sharing through FB app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Im using facebook SDK for iOS and when I open a popup to share a feed through the FB app, it doesn't work as the same way that the web-base popup.

These are the params:

```
    params = {
      method: "feed",
      link: "http://apps.facebook.com/mj-bubble-spinner/",
      picture: "http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg",
      name: "Facebook Dialogs",
      caption: "Reference Documentation",
      description: "testing",
      to: "1107189076"
    }
```

Everything works fine, but the difference is that the FB app doesn't use the parameter "to" (same occur with parameter "actions"). For the web-base popup everything works fine.

Thanks for any help,

Regards

Comment: This is correct and by design. The web dialog accepts a "to" parameter, whereas the graph API endpoint does not.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you know if there's a place or official documentation to check this info? Because it can be useful if I want to check for other features that works on web dialog only or vice versa

Comment: The web dialog reference doc is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ and the native share dialog's parameters are in the FBDialogs docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBDialogs/